# Does third party use of SO exempt questions from quality standards

Tags: discussion

I just came across [this in the reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/4909797).  The comment mentions that the third party vendor is now using SO for support.  It implies that maybe different standards should apply just because of that.

Are there different quality standards for questions, when associated with such vendors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no different quality standards. Just because spotify sent them here, it doesn't mean they get to ask lesser questions than we expect from anyone else.

Comment: I didnt think so, but the 25k commenter seemed to think so.  Thanks